# Is there a way to stop at a junit ant

Tags: java, ant, junit

I was wondering if it was at all possible through ant to stop at a specific test.
EX: I have the following tree structure:

```
test
  package1
    TU_file1.java
    TU_file2.java
  package2
    TU_file3.java
    TU_file4.java
```

I was wondering if I run ant through junit, is there a way I can run file1, 2, 3 and stop right there. I want to be able to grab the database before it runs my 4th failing test unit. I wanted a perfect environment before the 4th test runs. Is there a way to achieve this with filesets or patternsets. I know that there is the option failonerror, but I don't want it to run the 4th test at all.

Thanks!

Comment: why can't you reset /initialize the database in the setup(@BeforeClass or setup() ..) of the testcase programmatically?

Comment: The problem is the database isn't properly being cleaned up in the tearDown() method, and sometimes it's hard to find which one is leaving bad code behind. I wanted a way to grab a snapshot of everything that ran before the test and debug the test unit.

Answer (score 0):

An Ant solution is to add a fileset to the junit task:

```
<fileset dir="${src.tests}">
  <include name="**/TU_file*.java"/> <!-- or some other all inclusive pattern -->
  <exclude name="**/package2/TU_file4.java"/> <!-- exclude TU_file4.java -->
</fileset>
```

A JUnit 4.x solution is to add a @Ignore annotation to any test you want to exclude.

EDIT: If you want to halt execution before TU_file4 executes, add a @BeforeClass method that waits for input from System.in.

Comment: I don't want to exclude the test unit that's the problem. I want it to hault the moment before it hits TU_file4.java and not continue on. This solution is to just exclude a test unit. I want to make sure some other test unit above is failing to do some kind of cleanup or teardown. This technically would work if I only had 4 files and they were all TU_file?.java, but unfortunately that was just an example scenario.

Answer (score 0):

In your Ant build file, when calling the `<junit>` task, you can have it include a `<fileset>` element that can define which tests to run by pattern matching.  For your example, you could define the resource inside `<fileset>` to specifically exclude TU_file4.java.  See the [Apache documentation for the Ant JUnit Task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html) for more details.

That said, a best practice for your unit tests is that they shouldn't leave any cruft behind them after they finish.

Comment: I believe some test unit above might be leaving some unwanted items, which is why I want to hault the test unit before the 4th test, do some basic analysis and see if there is anything being left behind.

Comment: Does the same thing happen if you run the test by itself?  Or if you rub the tests in sequence by hand?  Those would be two alternative ways to get where you want to be as well. Good luck!

Comment: If I run the test alone, it will pass, but if I run with multiple tests it will fail. I think this is due to some static list that hold cached values for the JVM which would defiantly cause issues.

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider the java debug-mode? This may be a good choice to halt execution at a breakpoint with remote debugging.

e.g.:

Edit:

A Suite should always run the in the order you specified. 
If you want to sort the @Test Methods you have to create an own TestRunner (extend BlockJUnit4ClassRunner#computeTestMethods).
Pseudo code:

```
  @Override
  public List computeTestMethods()
  {
    List myList = super.computeTestMethods();
    Collections.sort(myList, new MyTestMethodComaparator());
    return myList;
  }
```

Comment: I tried running all the test units in eclipse, the only problem is the ordering in eclipse and ant are different. Ant does the junits in alphabetical order, and eclipse does it in some random order. If eclipse did it in alphabetical exactly like ant, then that would be perfect.

Comment: You could use Suites to ensure the order of the tests. The Suite-Classes are always executed in the given order.
Sorting test-Methods is a bit more complicated and discouraged by junit theory :). I did this by Writing my own TestRunner and Overriding the computeTestMethod() Method.

Comment: I don't think eclipse has a way to run junit tests in a specific order, like alphabetical based on test unit package names? This would help out a ton cause I could debug same way ant does.

Comment: I don't think that there is an out of the box solution. Maybe you could write your own implementation of the eclipse junit plugin or somehow overwrite their TestCollector.